# Application Logs are not generated if application is started from monit

Tags: spring-boot, log4j, monit

I have been facing a weird issue with monit. I am monitoring one spring boot application which uses log4j to generate logs. If the service is started with monit, no logs are being generated. If same .sh file is run manually from terminal, logs are being generated properly.

Below is monit config:

check process trading-center-service with pidfile /mnt/aiq-micro-services/trading-center-service/trading-center-service.pid
start program = "/mnt/aiq-micro-services/trading-center-service/trading-center.sh start" as uid "ubuntu" and gid "ubuntu"
stop program = "/mnt/aiq-micro-services/trading-center-service/trading-center.sh stop" as uid "ubuntu" and gid "ubuntu"

trading-center.sh :

start)
       exec java -Xmx4000M -Dspring.profiles.active=development -jar /mnt/aiq-micro-services/trading-center-service/trading-center-service.jar

Running java -jar command from terminal and trading-center.sh file from terminal generates logs properly but not when process is started from monit.

Comment: Are there any error messages you can share?

Comment: There are no errors related to application and application starts properly but logs are not created.

Comment: Where log4j is logging ? STDOUT or a file ?